# How to Extend Solr Terms Component Functionality

Tags: solr, autocomplete, components, autosuggest

I was using the `solr` terms component and it works great.

However, now I need the terms component filter by another field. I want to keep terms component because it can search in a case insensitive way, with regex you can search words inside words/phrases (not necessary the prefix), the terms component result is so easy to parse and it returns the exact information that I want for an autocomplete, but I want to filter by an additional field.

Is there a way to implement or extend this component functionality to do that? I don't want to use `solr` facet because it searches only by the prefix and it do not search for words in the middle in a case insensitive way (OR I am wrong?).

If you guys have another solution for this, let me know, but basically I want:

1. Implement a solr auto suggest over a multivalued field
2. Filter  suggestions by another field
3. My autosuggestion search should be   case insensitive
4. The autosuggestion search should suggest words   that are in the middle ex. `Field = "Hello World"`. The query `"wor"` should return the sample field.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it seems like the term component can't be filtered. As mentionned in the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent)

> In a sense, this component provides fast field faceting over the whole index (not restricted by the base query or any filters)

You should go another strategy

- copy your raw multivalued field (the one you want to search on) in two other ones.
- On one field, apply [edgengrams](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) after having tokenized (whitespace for example) your values, lets call it *keyword_ngram*
- Same on the other one, but do not tokenize it... and apply edgengrams too *phrase_ngram*

At last, let's assume that you have indexed following words & phrases:

- brown fox
- brown sugar
- honey is sugar
- the fox is brown

Now, do a [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) search, with following qf: **keyword_ngram^1 phrase_ngram^2**

This means that exact phrase matches will be better ranked than keyword matches.

Let's assume you search `?q=brow` , result should be:

- brown fox
- brown sugar
- the fox is brown

But if you search `?q=brown f`, result should be:

- brown fox
- the fox is brown

At last, apply a simple [query filter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) on the field you need...

Finaly, an excellent [concept of solr autocompletion](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Advanced-autocomplete-with-Solr-Ngrams-and-Twitters-typeaheadjs.aspx). Works very well, and is filterable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure if with "brown f" I need the result "The fox is brown". Also, I was thinking on many solutions and the problem of doing two copies of the same field is going to increase the index too much. I have thousands of documents and multiple fields that I want to implement autocomplete. So I think that have many copies and multiple fields with ngrams is going to increase so much the index. Have you experiment to try modifying the  Terms component to implement filters?